# How to add outputs of different iterations in java?

Tags: java

Hello i have recently started learning java and i came across a problem that really confused me. i wanted to take the last digit of number and raise the rest of the number to that power. For example : 212 would be 21^2. I did succeed in achieving the code necessary but the main problem i faced was when i had to add the outputs over different iterations. For example: if i had 2 inputs 32 and 46 i wanted to add 3^2+4^6 to get my desired output.

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int limit = sc.nextInt();


    for (int x = 0; x<= limit; x++) {

        int v = sc.nextInt();

        double c = v% 10;

        double e = (v-c)/10;

        System.out.println(Math.pow(e, c));
    }

}
```

Instead i got something like this:

```
    32
    9.0
    46
    4096.0
```

So if anyone can show me how to add those value it would be really helpful.

Comment: Try adding the result of Math.pow to a variable

Comment: You are printing in the loop itself. Where are u adding the two powered number after calculating the power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea but you need to keep adding the values you calculate to a total so you can print it out at the end:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("How many inputs?: ");
        int limit = sc.nextInt();

        double total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
            System.out.print("Value " + (i+1) + ": ");
            total += definedPower(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("The total is: " + total);
 }

private static double definedPower(int value) {
    double croppedValue =  value % 10;

    double e = (value-croppedValue)/10;

    return Math.pow(e, croppedValue);
}
```